# Highest Billboard 200 rank for a Creative Commons licensed album?

Tags: album, copyright, chart-success, billboard

Which album, released (also) under a [Creative Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons) license, had the highest [Billboard 200](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_200) chart success?

(The album must have been licensed under a CC license *before* it entered the charts, so it doesn’t count if it got released under CC *after* a chart success.)

Nine Inch Nails’ [*The Slip*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Slip_%28album%29) made it to [rank **13**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Slip_%28album%29#Chart_positions) (while [*Ghosts I–IV*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_I%E2%80%93IV) made it to [rank 14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_I%E2%80%93IV#Chart_positions)). Was there any more successful album?

Comment: If we suppose this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_major_Creative_Commons_licensed_works#Music) is up to date, no one exept NIN made it that high. Another notable artist made it to rank 52, [The Knife's *Shaking the Habitual*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaking_the_Habitual).